# Linq to MySql GetTable

Tags: c#, .net, database, linq-to-sql

I am trying to insert/add a data into my Database but it seems that this part of code won't work The name of the table that I am trying to add data on is "People"

```
Table<People> users = myDb.GetTable<People>;
```

Has an error on the `Table<People> users` why is this error occurring?? how would I fix this?

just in case you need the stack trace, here it is.

> Error 1
>   The type or namespace name 'Table' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)
>   C:\Users\John\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs    23  13  WindowsFormsApplication1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

```
using System.Data.Linq;
```

to the top of your file to bring the Table class into scope. Alternatively you could use:

```
var users = myDb.GetTable<People>();
```

Comment: thanks for reminding! btw are there Online Documentation which Explains to me what does this table do? like in java? there are Online Documentation and API's

Comment: The LINQ to SQL reference can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386934.aspx